# Scroll left with animation won't work anymore

Tags: javascript

I have this :

```
var box = document.getElementById('scroller');

box.animate( { left: '+=350' }, 1000);
```

Which will scroll back to zero just fine.

I would like to animate it,  tried :

```
box.animate( { scrollLeft: '+=350' }, 1000);
$('scroller').animate({ scrollLeft: 0 }, 500);
```

None works no matter what number I put there.

Comment: If you are using jquery, you need to call scroller like this: $('#scroller'). Unless you already put it in a variable ofcourse, but that i don't see in this code

Comment: thanks man ! works. publish an answer I will accept. (if you want)

Answer (score 0):

Basic mistake in syntax

```
$('scroller').animate({ scrollLeft: 0 }, 500);
```

it should be

```
$('#scroller').animate({ scrollLeft: 0 }, 500);
```